# Ubuntu Theme Changing

Tags: ubuntu

What dose change if you change the Theme in Ubuntu LTS 20.04? What Environment variables do change? I need this information for changing the theme in the Logic-Simulator Logisim. My system theme is dark but I can't read any text in dark mode only in light or stander theme! And I don't want to always switch themes back an forth! So I want to execute the programm with the specify Environment variables set for light theme! By the way logisim is an java application! I alerady tryed:

`GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light logisim`

and

`GTK_THEME=light logisim`

both didn't work!

Thanks for answering in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. I've just discovered a "workaround" that consists in running the .jar file with sudo:

```
sudo java -jar yourfile.jar
```

But I still believe that there is a formal solution to our problem.

Comment: Thanks, that realy works! If you don't want to execute a programm as root you can of cause create a new user change the theme on that account and use su to execute it as another user! I think that would work too!